# Can anyone tell me how to get the same Gnome desktop environment as the one in the photo?

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments

I have been using gnome fallback for more than a year, but recently I have come across this image:
[image]

However, when in virtual machine (new copy of ubuntu 12.04) I change to gnome 3 shell, the desktop is not even similar to the one in the photo above. I am wondering if there are others things that I am missing/have to do....to get to the same thing (or similar) that you can see in the image above.

NOTE: Here is a screenshot from the virtual machine after I used these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

[ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

[image]

Comment: it *might* be that the virtual machine doesnt have 3d acceleration thus falling back to something else. Again, its just a guess, i'm not sure if this is what is happening, would need more info.

Comment: Yes, may be there is something wrong with the graphics settings. Could you post a picture of the appearance in the virtual machine that you are getting?

Comment: sure...it is in the main body of my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install VirtualBox Guest Additions in order to use Gnome Shell. There is no need to add any PPAs. Gnome Shell is in Ubuntu. But it requires hardware accelerated graphics, which isn't available until you install the Guest Additions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Can you tell me what this Guest Additions adds to my existing VirtualBox?

Comment: Mostly graphics acceleration and features from your VGA that can't be used without it.

Answer (score -2):

I think installing gnome3 will do, if it doesn't bother you, however, you can install ubuntu gnome remix 12.10.1, which comes with gnome for default and doesn't leave all those nasty unity plugins or programs installed.